# Get html content from multiple pages and write into new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to be open multiple window and get the html content, and then I want to push or write into 
new html page. Is this possible?

**Example:**[Sample window-click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woGwy.png)
We have window1 and window2 (See mentioned picture) . Window1 contains paragraph1 and Window2 contains paragraph2,
I need to get this paragraph 1 and 2, write into window3

I have the code to write the new window, Please suggest or help to achieve my requirement?

**My Code:**

```
var url = document.getElementById('ifrmDivisionPage').src;
var tabOrWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
tabOrWindow.document.write( "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">" );
tabOrWindow.document.write( "<html>" );
tabOrWindow.document.write( "<head>" );
tabOrWindow.document.write( "<meta charset='utf-8'>" );
tabOrWindow.document.write("</head><body>");
tabOrWindow.document.write($("#ifrmDivisionPage").contents().find("body").html());
tabOrWindow.document.write("</body>");
 tabOrWindow.document.write("</html>");
```

Comment: Why not using XHR (ajax)?

Comment: can you please share any sample code example?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible. You can use many approaches to do this. Web crawling and web Scraping techniques will help you here. As an example try to load necessary URLs in iframes without opening them in different windows and then you can access their DOM elements easily. Then simply grab the necessary content using simple javascript and apply them wherever you want.

Comment: I have tried so many approaches. But I can't achieved using java script